# Reorder matrix columns based on colnames suffix and the order of a character vector

Tags: r, matrix, r-colnames

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
cols <- c("foo_AFG", "baz_SYR", "baz_TUR", "foo_SYR", "foo_TUR", "baz_AFG")
foo <- matrix(ncol = length(cols))
colnames(foo) <- cols
w <- c("SYR", "AFG", "TUR")
```

**foo**

```
     foo_AFG baz_SYR baz_TUR foo_SYR foo_TUR baz_AFG
[1,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

I would like to reorder the columns of `foo` so that the suffix of their names resembles the order of `w`. I only care about the suffixes (all that comes after the `"_"` separator).

Examples of what I want (and one of what I DON'T want):

```
# this is OK
     foo_SYR baz_SYR baz_AFG foo_AFG foo_TUR baz_TUR
[1,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA

# this is OK
     baz_SYR foo_SYR baz_AFG foo_AFG baz_TUR foo_TUR
[1,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA

# this is NOT OK
     foo_SYR foo_AFG foo_TUR baz_SYR baz_AFG baz_TUR
[1,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an ordered factor only based on the suffix part (extracted with `gsub`), and use `order` + `[` to arrange the columns.

```r
ord_fac <- ordered(gsub(".*_", "", colnames(foo)), levels = w)
foo[, order(ord_fac)]

#   baz_SYR foo_SYR foo_AFG baz_AFG baz_TUR foo_TUR
# 1      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Maybe an "ordered" factor is not necessary. An ordinary factor is ok. Good work!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `match()` + `order()`:

```r
foo[, order(match(sub(".*_", "", colnames(foo)), w))]

# baz_SYR foo_SYR foo_AFG baz_AFG baz_TUR foo_TUR 
#      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
```

Comment: Thanks! I have accpeted @Maël answer since it came first and it worked but I upvoted yours and I appreciated it :)